# The input changes when taking input from two different files

Tags: c++

I take input from a txt file (say a.txt) save it in a variable say `a`, I close the connection. I then take input from another txt file(say b.txt) and save it in a different variable say `b`, I close the connection. 
Now I output the variables in a different text file(c.txt).  The outputted value of variable `b` changes and becomes different from the one present in the input text file b.txt.  I even tried using `fflush` (stdin) but results did not change.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    freopen("a.txt","r",stdin);
    cin>>a;
    fflush(stdin);
    fclose(stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    freopen("b.txt","r",stdin);
    cin>>b;
    fflush(stdin);
    fclose(stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    freopen("c.txt","w",stdout);
    cout<<"a= "<<a<<endl<<"b= "<<b<<endl;
    fflush(stdin);
    fclose(stdout);
    fflush(stdin);
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Always add checks to make sure that reading from any stream, whether it is `cin`, `stdin`, or a `FILE*`, that the operation is successful before using the data. Also, check the return value of `freopen` to make sure it was succesful.

Comment: FWIW, it works in my environment - cygwin64/g++.

Comment: `fflush` with an input stream is undefined.

Comment: Do you haveca reason not to just use `std::ifstream`/`ofstream`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using fstream.h library. e.g;

```
#include<iostream>
//fstream is the library from which we use file input and output resources.
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

/*
There are three basic operations, you already know about
1. LOAD | we load any thing on which we are supposed to work, into MAIN     MEMORY i.e. RAM
2. PROCESS | any task we are supposed to do on it.
3. STORE | write data back onto STORAGE i.e. HARD DISK
*/

int main()
{
    //*************************INPUT FORM FILE****************************//
    //to get data from file
    //file input variable declaration
    ifstream fin;

    //load the file into memory
    //file.txt must exists in same folder where you placed your cpp file.
    fin.open("file.txt");

    char x[100];

    //tp get data from file.
    fin >> x;
    cout << "Data from file.txt is :: " << x << endl;

    //now as we are done taking input from file.
    //so now we must close the open file.
    fin.close();
    //*************************INPUT FORM FILE****************************//


    cout << "\n\n\n";

    //*************************SAVING DATA INTO FILE | FILE REPACE CODE****************************//
    //to enter a data in a file
    ofstream fout;

    //load the file into memory
    //file.txt must exists in same folder where you placed your cpp file.
    // if file isn;t available then fout will create the file with specified name
    fout.open("file.txt");

    char str[100];
    //to get data from console.
    cout << "Enter some string to write in file.txt (file replace mode)" << endl;
    cin >>str;

    cout << "Writing data into file now." << endl;
    fout << str;

    //now as we are done saving data into file.
    //so now we must close the opened file.
    fout.close();
    //*************************SAVING DATA INTO FILE | FILE REPACE CODE****************************//

     /*
     remember code o fout given above will replace data
     */


    cout << "\n\n\n";

     ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //*************************SAVING DATA INTO FILE | FILE APPEND CODE****************************//
    //to enter a data in a file
    ofstream fout2;

    //load the file into memory
    //file.txt must exists in same folder where you placed your cpp file.
    // if file isn;t available then fout2 will create the file with specified name
    fout2.open("file.txt", ios::app);

    //to get data from console.
    cout << "Enter some string to write in file.txt (Append mode)" << endl;
    cin >> str;
    cout << "Data from console. is " << str << endl;

    cout << "Writing data into file now." << endl;
    fout2 << str;



    cout << "\n\n\n";
    cout << "\n\n\n";
    //now as we are done saving data into file.
    //so now we must close the opened file.
    fout2.close();

    fout2.open("file.txt", ios::app);

    //to get data from console.
    cout << "Enter some string to write in file.txt *(append mode)" << endl;
    cin >> str;
    cout << "Data from console. is " << str << endl;

    cout << "Writing data into file now." << endl;
    fout2 << str;

    //now as we are done saving data into file.
    //so now we must close the opened file.
    fout2.close();
    //*************************SAVING DATA INTO FILE | FILE APPEND CODE****************************//

    return 0;
}
//This code is actually written by a friend of mine , Ammar Tahir :)
```